# Responsive CSS /java script DIV - show on click only on mobile query

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, navigation

I have looked all over online trying to solve this problem. I am in the process of making a desktop website responsive for mobile and have run into issues with the Navigation menu. I have set it to `display:none` for the mobile version but I want to make it so it can be seen by clicking on either an image or text. The solution that I have found elsewhere have all only worked with a div menu that only has `UL` and `LI` elements in it. Mine has `H2` tags for each "section", etc. I just would rather have a button click and bam the whole `DIV` shows up just on a mobile query without messing with any of my HTML code, etc.

I have found this jquery code that seems close, however it seems to hide the nav div on desktop. I need it to work with `display:none` only set in the media query via CSS.

```
$("#preview").toggle(function() {
    $("#navi").hide();
}, function() {
    $("#navi").show();
});
```

});

It gets called by just clicking on the text such as "Click here for menu"...Would also prefer that to be a button or a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$.toggleClass()` instead of using `$.hide()`. This way the media query css will have more control. The following is an example that a button that hides a div only in screen smaller than 700px.

JS:

```
$("#preview").toggleClass('hideInMobile');
```

Css:

```
@media (max-width: 700px){
    .hideInMobile 
    {
        display:none
    }
}
```

demo:http://jsfiddle.net/HZDCW/2/

Hope it helps.

Comment: You could also use `.slideToggle();` and some easing to make it look a little smoother.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reponsive. I tried doing this but it still does not work for me. Perhaps I did something wrong? The div that it would be hiding and showing is #navi.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#preview').toggleClass('#navi');
})
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#preview {
}
@media (max-width: 700px){
#navi {display:none}
</style></head>

Comment: I added the button code in a div called preview. .. Thanks sorry for the messy posts.. I am new here :P

Comment: #navi is a **id**, not a **class**. You need a class name similar to what I had in the example demo. Also, `toggleClass('classname')` add/remove class on the element you apply to, so if `#preview` is a button, then it's wrong. See http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/ for more details.

Comment: Is there a way to make it work with the id? I even tried adding class="hideinMobile"> in the id and it still does not work. Using this now: $('button').click(function(){
    $('#navi').toggleClass('hideInMobile');
})                                                                    Sorry Im not very good at coding or understanding this stuff. :(

Comment: Also tried $('button').click(function(){
    $('navi').toggleClass('hideInMobile');
})

Comment: <div id="navi" class="hideInMobile">

Comment: `$('button').click(function(){ $('#navi').toggleClass('hideInMobile'); })` looks good to me, might be something wrong with your css and html. Try change id and class to whatever you want in the [demo page](http://jsfiddle.net/HZDCW/2/) I provided and click "update".  Then you can create your version of demo that easier for others to see and understand. and post the link :)

Comment: I made a demo of it and it works great. Unfortunately it does not work on an HTML page for me. http://jsfiddle.net/HZDCW/4/ Either in Dreamweaver or wordpress where i am throwing it in. Dunno what I am doing wrong.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#navi').toggleClass('hideInMobile');
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
@media (max-width: 700px){
.hideInMobile {display:none}
{
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="navi" class="hideInMobile">
    <H2>Hello</H2>
    <ul>
<li>Testing </li>
</ul>
</div>
    <p> more content more content more content </p>
<button>Click Me</button>

Comment: I got it to work!! I found out how to view the source from Jsfiddle and it showed the javascript on the bottom right before body tag. Now it seems to work great. Thank you so much.

Comment: Also is there a way to make it use a CSS text button or an image instead of the push button being used?

Comment: glad to hear that you got it work. just change `$('button')` to the thing you want to click on. if you have a image `<img href="button.jpg" class="imgButton" />`, then it will be $('.imgButton');

Comment: Thank you so much that worked great. You are a lifesaver. Saved the rest of my weekend. ;)